# Is there a way to keep a view always visible in ZStack in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I have a view that I'd like to completely cover at some point and I'd like just one particular child view not to be covered. Is this possible in SwiftUI?

See this code for example:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct ZIndexExperimentApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showCover = false
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                Text("Normal text")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .padding()
                Text("Text that should always be visible")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .padding()
                Spacer()
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

            if self.showCover {
                VStack {
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(Color.blue)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                }
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            }
        }
        .onAppear(perform: {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
                self.showCover = true
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Is there a way to make the second `Text` to be on top of the cover? I tried to set the `zindex` on it to a high value but it didn't seem to have an effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using the **foregroundColor or hidden** is the better way, because if you kill some Views in your screen you would be notice some displacement on View which is not pleasant for user.

---

**Version 1:**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var showCover: Bool = Bool()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            
            if showCover { Color.blue }
            
            VStack {
                
                Spacer()
                
                Text("Normal text")
                    .foregroundColor(showCover ? Color.clear : Color.primary)
                    .padding()
                
                Text("Text that should always be visible")
                    .padding()
                
                Spacer()
            }
            
        }
        .font(.headline)
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .onAppear() { DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(3)) { showCover = true } }
        
    }
}
```

---

**Version 2:**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var showCover: Bool = Bool()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            
            if showCover { Color.blue }
            
            VStack {
                
                Spacer()
                
                if showCover { Text("Normal text").padding().hidden() }
                else { Text("Normal text").padding() }
                
                Text("Text that should always be visible")
                    .padding()
                
                Spacer()
            }
            
        }
        .font(.headline)
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .onAppear() { DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(3)) { showCover = true } }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Using hidden seems to be a good substitute indeed. Thanks!